# window.onbeforeunload not doing what is wanted

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use the window.onbeforeunload method to remove a bunch of session variables if the user unloads the screen by closing the tab.
Here is my function:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
        return 'Are you sure you want to leave this page?  You will lose any unsaved data.';
        document.getElementById('<%=btnFinshed%>').click();
        return null;
    };  
</script>
```

I added the return message just to see if it was firing at all, but there it gets even more confusing. Instead of displaying my message, I get this one (on Mozilla):

This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave - data you have entered may not be saved.

IE does something similar.

My btnFinshed_click is not firing, whether I put my message in or not and the subsequent retaining of session variables that need to be removed causes errors further on.

Any ideas?

OK. I added another button, and another javascript function, just to test this document.getElementById command. The result is document.getElementById definitely does not work. Here is the routine:

```
    <script  language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
       function testThis(e) {
           var element1 = document.getElementById('<%=btnFinished%>');
           if (element1 != null) {
               alert("element is found");
               //code to set the value variable.
               document.getElementById('<%=btnFinished%>').fireEvent("onclick");
           }
           else {
               alert("element is null");
           }
           return false;
       };
</script>  

    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="X" OnClientClick="testThis()" />

    <asp:Button ID="btnFinished" runat="server" Text="Finished" onclick="btnFinshed_Click" CausesValidation="False" /> - i renamed this button too.
```

The result - document.getElementById does NOT work. The element is clearly there. The id is clearly correct. The javascript command must be duff.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    var e = e || window.event,
        msg = 'Are you sure you want to leave this page?  You will lose any unsaved data.';
    if (e) {
        e.returnValue = msg;
    }
    return msg;
};
```

Comment: That made no differnce whatsoever. I am more concerned about getting my button click to fire.

Comment: Try returning '<%=btnFinshed%>' to check if this alerts the correct value.

Comment: BTW are you sure this is not just a typo? btnFinished instead of btnFinshed ?

Comment: No,the control is definitely called btnFinshed !

Comment: OK. I added another button, and another javascript function, just to test this document.getElementById command. The result is document.getElementById definitely does not work. Here is the routine:

Comment: Finally got it working. The scripts had to come after the definition for btnFinished on the page, and it did not like <%=btnFinished%>. When I replaced this with btnFinished, it worked.